# Почему не меняется кнопка при открытии списка JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть таблица такого типа:

```
   <table id="UsersTable" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>ФИО</th>
                <th>Компания</th>
                <th>Должность</th>
                <th>Телефон</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var items in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td id ="idrow" class="details-control" data-assigned-id="@items.ADUsersId">@items.ADUsersId</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.DisplayName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.Company)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.Department)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.TelephoneNumber)</td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Все работает нормально вроде как, но в Jquery я не особо силен. Дело в том ,что при нажатии кнопки в столбце раскрывается список и должна соотвественно меняется кнопка, но у меня этого не происходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии должна появиться кнопка с минусом. 
Вот мой CSS

```
td.details-control {
    background: url('img/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
td.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('img/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

А вот сам JQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#UsersTable').DataTable({
            "iDisplayLength": 5,
            "language": { "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Russian.json" },
        });
        $('#UsersTable').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
            var td = $(this).closest('td');
            var row = table.row(td);
            var id = $('#idrow').attr('data-assigned-id');
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Details", "Users")',
                type: 'post',
                data: { id: id },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (row.child.isShown()) {
                        row.child.hide();
                        td.removeClass('shown');
                    } else {
                        // Open this row
                        row.child(format({
                            'ФИО': data.DisplayName,
                            'ФИО': data.DisplayName
                        })).show();
                        td.addClass('shown');
                    }
                }, 
            });
        });
    });
```

Что я делаю не так? И еще, почему то вот сюда `var id = $('#idrow').attr('data-assigned-id');`  у меня попадают неверные данные. Но это наверное второй вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить

```
td.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('img/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

на

```
td.shown {
    background: url('img/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

и

```
$('#UsersTable').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var td = $(this).closest('td');
        var row = table.row(td);
        var id = $('#idrow').attr('data-assigned-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Details", "Users")',
            type: 'post',
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    row.child.hide();
                    td.removeClass('shown');
                } else {
                    // Open this row
                    row.child(format({
                        'ФИО': data.DisplayName,
                        'ФИО': data.DisplayName
                    })).show();
                    td.addClass('shown');
                }
            }, 
        });
    });
```

на

```
    $('#UsersTable').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('shown');
        var row = table.row(td);
        var id = $(this).attr('data-assigned-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Details", "Users")',
            type: 'post',
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                row.child(format({
                    'ФИО': data.DisplayName,
                    'ФИО': data.DisplayName
                })).show();
            }, 
        });
    });
```

Comment: Да огромное спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: Кнопка не меняется(

Comment: @shatoidil обновил ответ

Comment: Поменял стили и все заработало. Поменял скрипт выдает ошибку Index:2246 Uncaught ReferenceError: td is not defined

Comment: @shatoidil забыл добавить `var td = $(this).closest('td');`

Comment: @shatoidil если работает нормально не поменяйте скрипт просто измените стил

Comment: Да спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#UsersTable').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
  var td = $(this);
  var row = table.row(this);
  var id = $(this).attr('data-assigned-id');
  ...
```

Comment: Данные теперь передаются верно, но кнопка при открытии списка все равно  не меняется.